# UseEffect Interfiere con la Alerta para enviar datos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola buenas queria saber por que mi alertas no funciona cuado agrego mi useEffect adjunto codigo

useEffect

```
const [alerta,setAlerta] = useState({})
useEffect(()=>{
setDatosMdp({
   fechaInicio:dat.fechaInicio, //FALTA
   fechaTermino:dat.fechaTermino, //FALTA
   latitudNorte:dat.latitudNorte,
   latitudSur:dat.latitudSur,
   longitudOriente:dat.longitudOriente,
   longitudPoniente:dat.longitudPoniente,
   emergencia:dat.emergencia       //FALTA
 })
},[dat])
```

adjunto ArrowFunction donde hace el submit al formulario y La alerta el if no me lo toma en cuenta y pasa directamente a enviar la solicitud cuando tengo el effect

```
 const FormMDP = e =>{
e.preventDefault()


if(Object.values(datosMdp).includes('')){
  setAlerta({msg: 'Hay Campos Vacios',error:true })
  return
}   
SubmitMDP(datosMdp)

setAlerta({ msg:'Solicitud Enviada'})
setDatosMdp('')

}
```

Comment: Ls estructura `datosMdp` debe tener al menos una de sus propiedades vacia para que el if se ejecute, ¿Estas seguro que entra al `if`? pon un console ahi dentro para que confirmes si esta entrando.

Comment: esto ejecutara una vez cambie `dat` este esta cambiando? donde?